# Microsoft Publisher 2016 Lacks [x of y] page numbering - How to achieve this?

Tags: microsoft-office, vba, macros, microsoft-publisher

Simply put, our office has been using MS Word for their training documentation.  As I began inserting a large number of photos, this caused Word's formatting to break in the most frustrating ways possible.  As I am full of ideas I suggested we move to Publisher, which makes managing text and images easy.

Of course, our technical writer hit a roadblock right away.  MS Word allows page headers to be numbered automatically, both the number of the current page as well as the total number of pages.  For example " Page 1 of 3 "

MS Publisher only supports the automatic numbering of pages, nothing more.  I looked around online and found a brief VBA Macro for this very problem:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_other-mso_other-mso_2010/display-page-numbers-in-ms-publisher-2010/499026db-0f47-46a8-8f96-6ee0b0ca7d46

```
Dim strPageNumber As String
Dim x As Integer
For x = 1 To Pages.Count
    With ActiveDocument.Pages(x)
        strPageNumber = .PageNumber
        .Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=pbTextOrientationHorizontal, _
            Left:=710, Top:=580, Width:=80, Height:=20) _
            .TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter NewText:="Page " _
            & strPageNumber & " of " & .Parent.Count & "."
    End With
Next x
```

I can see that a text box is being created, which seems unnecessary.  Would it not be possible to use VBA Macro to just insert the total number of pages automatically in the document where I select?

Unfortunately, I have no clue how to implement this.  It does seem to be a major oversight on Microsoft's part.

For now, the plan is to jump to the last page, get the page number and edit the "of" number in the master by hand.  Super awkward.